# How do I shutdown and reconfigure an AsyncHttpClient that is using NettyAsyncHttpProvider

Tags: java, netty, asynchttpclient

I'm constructing an `AsyncHttpClient` like this:

```
public AsyncHttpClient getAsyncHttpClient() {
    AsyncHttpClientConfig config = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
                    .setProxyServer(makeProxyServer())
                    .setRequestTimeoutInMs((int) Duration.create(ASYNC_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES).toMillis())
                    .build();

    return new AsyncHttpClient(new NettyAsyncHttpProvider(config), config);
}
```

This gets called once at startup, and then the return value is passed around and used in various places. `makeProxyServer()` is my own function to take my proxy settings an return a `ProxyServer` object. What I need to do is be able to change the proxy server settings and then recreate the `AsyncHttpClient` object. But, I don't know how to shut it down cleanly. A bit of searching on leads me to believe that `close()` isn't gracefull. I'm worried about spinning up a whole new executor and set of threads every time the proxy settings change. This won't be often, but my application is very long-running.

I know I can use `RequestBuilder.setProxyServer()` for each request, but I'd like to have it set in one spot so that all callers of my `asyncHttpClient` instance obey the system-wide proxy settings without each developer having to remember to do it.

What's the right way to re-configure or teardown and rebuild a `Netty`-based `AsyncHttpClient`?

Comment: Heh, I just got the tumbleweed badge for this question. As I mentioned in the question, I worked around this by doing setProxyServer() per-request, but the overall problem of being able to shutdown and rebuild a Netty-based AsyncHttpClient seems like it would interest more people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with using `AsyncHttpClient.close()` is that it shuts down the thread pool executor used by the provider, then there is no way to re-use the client without re-building it, because as per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), the executor instance cannot be reused once ts is shutdown. So, there is no way but re-build the client if you go that way (unless you implement your own ExecutorService that would have another shutdown logic, but it is a long way to go, IMHO).

However, from looking into the implementation of `NettyAsyncHttpProvider`, I can see that it stores the reference to the given `AsyncHttpClientConfig`instance and calls its `getProxyServerSelector()` to get the proxy settings for every new `NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(Request...)` invocation (i.e. for every request executed by `AsyncHttpClient`).

Then, if we could make the `getProxyServerSelector()` return the configurable instance of `ProxyServerSelector`, that would do the thing.

Unfortunately, `AsyncHttpClientConfig` is designed to be a read-only container, instantiated by `AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder`. 
To overcome this limitation, we would have to hack it, using, say, "wrap/delegate" approach:

- Create a new class, derived from `AsyncHttpClientConfig`. The class should wrap the given separate `AsyncHttpClientConfig` instance and implement the delegation of the `AsyncHttpClientConfig` getters to that instance.
- To be able to return the proxy selector we want at any given point of time, we make this setting mutable in a this wrapper class and expose the setter for it.

Example:

```
public class MyAsyncHttpClientConfig extends AsyncHttpClientConfig
{
  private final AsyncHttpClientConfig config;
  private ProxyServerSelector proxyServerSelector;

  public MyAsyncHttpClientConfig(AsyncHttpClientConfig config)
  {
    this.config = config;
  }

  @Override
  public int getMaxTotalConnections() { return config.maxTotalConnections; }

  @Override
  public int getMaxConnectionPerHost() { return config.maxConnectionPerHost; }

  // delegate the others but getProxyServerSelector()

  ...

  @Override
  public ProxyServerSelector getProxyServerSelector()
  { 
    return proxyServerSelector == null 
      ? config.getProxyServerSelector()
      : proxyServerSelector; 
  }

  public void setProxyServerSelector(ProxyServerSelector proxyServerSelector) 
  { 
    this.proxyServerSelector = proxyServerSelector;
  }
}
```

- Now, in your example, wrap your `AsyncHttpClient` config instance with our new wrapper and use it to configure the `AsyncHttpClient`:

Example:

```
MyAsyncHttpClientConfig myConfig = new MyAsyncHttpClientConfig(config); 
return new AsyncHttpClient(new NettyAsyncHttpProvider(myConfig), myConfig);
```

- Whenever you invoke `myConfig.setProxyServerSelector(newSelector)`, the new request executed by `NettyAsyncHttpProvider` instance in your client will use the new proxy server settings.

A few hints/warnings:

- This approach relies on the internal implementation of `NettyAsyncHttpProvider`; therefore make your own judgement on maintainability, future Netty libraries versions upgrade strategy etc. You could always look at the Netty source code before upgrading to the new version. At the current point, I personally think it is unlikely to change too much to invalidate this implementation.
- You could get `ProxyServerSelector` for `ProxyServer` by using `com.ning.http.util.ProxyUtils.createProxyServerSelector(proxyServer)` - that's exactly what `AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder` does.
- The given example has no synchronization logic for accessing `proxyServerSelector`; you may want to add some as your application logic needs.
- Maybe it is a good idea to submit a feature request for `AsyncHttpClient` to be able to setup a "configuration factory" for the `AsyncHttpProvider` so all these complications would vanish :-)

Comment: In fact, AsyncHttpClientConfig has a protected proxyServerSelector field of ProxyServerSelector type; it could be re-used in MyAsyncHttpClientConfig to store the mutable ProxyServerSelector value.

Answer (score 1):

You should be holding a RequestHandle instance for all your unfinished requests.  When you want to shut down, you can loop through and call isFinished() on all of them until they are all done.  Then you know you can safely close it and no pending requests will be killed.

Once it's closed, just build a new one.  Don't try to reuse the existing one.  If you have references to it around, change those to reference a Factory that will return the current one.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment to the answer about close(), not a whole new answer.

Comment: Edited to recommend "building" a new Object instead of trying to re-use the current one.  The mentioned concern was around spinning up new executors because it's a long lived app.  Since close will stop existing ones (according to @NSH), this would not be an issue.